# How can I upload an image file from saved NSUserDefault to php server?

Tags: objective-c, image, uiimagepickercontroller, afnetworking

I would like to change profile image in my apps and upload the image to PHP server after edited. So far I saved my changed profile image to local.

My question is how can I upload the changed image to PHP server (upload image file)? Can I use AFNetworking 3.X and I need to write backend API for this case? Is there any method to upload the image file to server directly?

Here is what I done so far by using UIImagePickerController and it is working fine until this stage:-

```
-(void)changeProfileImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    if (!_photoManager) {
        _photoManager =[[SelectPhotoManager alloc]init];
    }
    [_photoManager startSelectPhotoWithImageName:@"Select Profile Image"];
    __weak typeof(self)mySelf=self;
    //Select Photo
    _photoManager.successHandle=^(SelectPhotoManager *manager,UIImage *image){

        mySelf.imgProfileImage.image = image;
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"imgProfile"];
    };
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do not store images in `NSUserDefaults`. Write the image to a file.

Comment: You must have API at backend to accept and store the file at particular place and also to set the path of the profile picture url in your backend database. So the next time it can return the correct profile picture.

Comment: @rmaddy, noted on that. Thanks!

Comment: @max9xs, thanks for your tips. Any sample I can refer to for image upload API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // HTTP method to upload file to web server
-(void)initWithURL:(NSString *)url image:(NSData *)imageData andFileName:(NSString *)filename delegate:(id)del {
    // your PHP server url
    // your image data
    NSString *urlString = url;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // if access token defined for authrization
    NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[[[CommonUserDefault getUserInfo] objectForKey:@"token"] objectForKey:@"accessToken"]];
    [request addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

        //return and test
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:nil];
     NSLog(@"json upload picture = %@",json);

    int statusCode = [[json objectForKey:@"statusCode"] intValue];
    if(statusCode == <errorCode>){
    }
}
```